# How to animate UISearchbar frame change keeping the rounded caps?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uisearchbar, uiviewanimation

I would like to animate the frame change of the UISearchbar. I would like it to expand and collapse when tapped on a search button.

Am using `UIViewAnimationBlock` to animate

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                         animations:^{
                             //Set the frame you want to the search bar
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }];
```

I have to expand the frame from zero and collapse it back. But while animating, the search bar loses its rounded edges and becomes a rectangle. Here is a screenshot of it while still animating[image]

Well it doesn't look good.. I want it to keep its rounded edges while expanding or collapsing. Is it possible ? If yes how ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change height of a UISearchBar try setting frames with height of 44px.

And if you want to change height then use CGAffineTransformMakeScale like..

```
//FOR EXPAND USE THIS:

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                         animations:^{
                             self.searchBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }];
```

and

//FOR EXPAND USE THIS:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                         animations:^{
                             self.searchBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.001, 0.001);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }];
```